# I need to increase the size of a span or div in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to increase the size of a span or div in my twitter bootstrap layout,
the layout is fluid and basically all I am looking to do is remove that gap on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Please be more specific and provide some code that shows what you've tried so far. It's slightly difficult to tell what you're asking from what you've provided. After all, almost all layout containers are a "span or div".

Comment: the code is in viewsource.. i changed fluid-container to remove padding-left:0; and remove padding-right:0;

Comment: I deleted my old answer because it did not answer the question (misunderstood it). I believe the new one addresses the actual issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the size of the `.span9` div so that it fills up the `.row-fluid`

```
.row-fluid .span9 {
    width: 77.01%; //Adjust this as necessary if there is more blank space.
}
```

This is only necessary because you manually modified the margins of the `.span9` with `margin-left: -2px`.

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the most of your design:

1. in bootstrap.css line number 4560 remove :

   ```
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
   ```
2. you have two options:

a. remove **margin-left: -2px;** so that gap on the right side of the screen will be removed ***but you will have margin between*** your right side and left side.

b. if you don't need your right side and left side to have a margin in between then you must change the value of **line 251 in bootstrap-responsive.css** to be equal to **77%** or play with the value to get the best number for your site.

last solution is to wrapping your **( span 3 and span 9 )** and make the width of the wrapper  100%.

e.g:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="anyClassName">  <!-- wrapper -->
       <div class="span3"> your code her </div>
       <div class="span9"> your code her </div>
      </div>    <!-- /wrapper -->
    </div>
</div>
```

then target the class using your css code like:

```
.anyClassName {
 width: 100%;
}
```

hope this will help you.